# MongoDB Error: "not authorized for query on admin.system.users"

Tags: mongodb, authentication

How to setup authentication on MongoDB using the following configuration ?

2 mongoD instances, sharded collections.
1 mongoS instance on another server. 
1 mongoD as a config server.

Whenever a turn on auth on mongod, i'm not enabled to logon on any servers, the users are created but i still can't login. The following error appear when trying to logon on mongoS instance:

**$err: "not authorized for query on admin.system.users"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a problem like I had it is likely that you could not query anything (with similar messages that you are not authorized).

By accident I noticed if I run two different versions of mongo daemon (win7/ent) second daemon starts but does not care if other mongo is listening, so it is unclear which daemon takes requests.

When I stopped all daemons and started one, everything started working. (for me)

Comment: I believe it would be possible to run two instances on same cpu providing they bind to different ports.

Comment: Thanks ljgww, i solved the problem shutting down all instances on mongoD,S,C, starting them without authentication, creating all users first and them restarting all mongo instances with authentication. By the way was my fault to not understand properly all the "roles" thing of mongo making me trying to query with a superadmin user that was not in the role "queryInAnyDatabase" or similar.